# .net core Client doesn't authenticate with IdentityServer v3 - Offset in Audience

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver3

**Given:**

IdentityServer v3
JavaSCript Client 
Asp Core Api  Client

The JavaScript client authenticates with the identityserver and makes a request with a bearer token to the api

the api is configured to use ressource owner workflow

**Problem:**
Now I get:

> Audiences: 'http://localhost/identity/resources'. Did not match:
>   validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'MyApi' or
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'

Obiviously Audiance doesn't match. 
what am I missing?

**Config**

ApiClient in Identity server:

```
 return new Client
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "MyApi",
                ClientName = "The client for the Groupl Api",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("foo".Sha256())
                },
                Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                AllowedScopes = ClientConstants.AllowedGrouplScopes()
            };
```

In the api to connect to identity server:

```
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();


        var authority = config["identity:authority:url"];
        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = authority,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            EnableCaching = false,

            ApiName = "myApi", //Correct that this is the client id?
            ApiSecret = "foo"
        });
```

Here the request (Access_token omitted)

```
GET /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59364
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

---

Update

when I set `LegacyAudienceValidation = true`, everything works fine, but i'm not sure how to handle this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is that authentication behavior changed. IdentityServer 3 didn't support multiple audiences. Identityserver 4 does. So for the old handling `LegacyAudienceValidation`  has to be set to `true`