# AspCore 2.0 and IdentityServer v3, Audience Validation Fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver3, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authentication

**Given:**

- IdentityServer v3
- Client WebApp with aspcore 2.0

**Scenario:**

When using aspcore 1.1 with Identity Server v3 I needed to set  `LegacyAudienceValidation = true` (see [.net core Client doesn't authenticate with IdentityServer v3 - Offset in Audience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670034/net-core-client-doesnt-authenticate-with-identityserver-v3-offset-in-audience)(

Now I migrate to .net core 2.0. and following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) to migrate identity there are other options and in core 1.0

**Problem:**
So there isn't anymore the `LegacyAudienceValidation` property and as a result i get audienace validation errors.

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException:
>   IDX10208: Unable to validate audience.
>   validationParameters.ValidAudience is null or whitespace and
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences is null.

My Client config code looks like this

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
         {
             options.Authority = Authority;
```

Am I missing something the aspcore api or are there any hints how to fix this gap?

Comment: set your Audience your API name. options.Audience = "API Name"

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation nuget package, and set LegacyAudienceValidation

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "identityserver";
                options.ApiName = "yourapi";
                options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;  // to make core 2.0 work with idsrv3
            });
```

Comment: I know this is late but it's worth noting the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package works on clients that connect to a IdSvr3 instance.